# mapping through an array of objects will update all of my react-switch components when it should only update one onChange

Tags: reactjs, onchange, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to make a table where I can edit store hours. I'm using the `Switch` component from `react-switch` and mapping through the days of the week. The problem is that every time I click on one `switch` element, all of the switch elements are all updating, however, I only want the one I'm clicking on to update.

The react-switch documentation requires an `onChange` and a `checked` prop, and it looks like I cannot pass an `onClick`.

Here's the element that I'm trying to render:

```
import Switch from "react-switch";
import  { regularHours }from '../../../helpers/momentFunctions';
import { FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
import { Styles } from './Styles/EditDaysOfWeekStyles';

export const EditDaysOfWeek = () => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
    const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked(!checked);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {regularHours.map(({ i, day }) => (
          <Styles>
              <div key={i}>{day}</div>
              <FormGroup key={i}>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="8:00AM" />
              </FormGroup>
              <p>-</p>
              <FormGroup key={i}>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="8:00PM" />
              </FormGroup>
              <Switch
                checked={checked}
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue={true}
                onColor="#2bbbae"
                offColor="#f15a29"
              />
            </Styles>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Here's the data structure:

```
export const sunday = moment.weekdays(0);
export const monday = moment.weekdays(1);
export const tuesday = moment.weekdays(2);
export const wednesday = moment.weekdays(3);
export const thursday = moment.weekdays(4);
export const friday = moment.weekdays(5);
export const saturday = moment.weekdays(6);

export const regularHours = [
    {
      day: sunday,
      index: 0,
    },
    {
      day: monday,
      index: 1,
    },
    {
      day: tuesday,
      index: 2,
    },
    {
      day: wednesday,
      index: 3,
    },
    {
      day: thursday,
      index: 4,
    },
    {
      day: friday,
      index: 5,
    },
    {
      day: saturday,
      index: 6,
    }
  ];
```

If you need a full view - I made a sandbox to play around in:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-leftpad-lt7y2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the same `checked` value and same `handleChange` function to every `<Switch />` without differentiating between them.

You need to have a separate `checked` state for each `<Switch />` if you don't want them to all have the same value.

I made some changes to your sandbox that gets it working as expected. (All edits are in `Day.js`)

[image: Edit immutable-wildflower-ny456]

Comment: Thanks, I actually converted it to a functional component since I'm trying to use hooks. Here's my link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-shape-fncfn